# Different Firebase Refs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I recently joined an international development project using firebase and I recently found an issue regarding firestore refs. In firestore, we have a single collection that has `student` docs where there exists a field called `teamDocRef` which is a reference to a different document called `team` under a different collection of teams.

When I retrieve the student doc, I want to be able to then read the `team` doc using the reference from my student doc.

When I retrieve the data from student doc and then do a `studentDoc.data().teamDocRef.get()` I am successfully able to retrieve the document of team with the ref showing up as:
[this ref obj in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvuPH.png)

This works great, but the problem we have is that one of my teammates is unable to use `get` on this ref because it says that the ref does not exist. Note. this is the EXACT same code that i am running and I still fail to get an error.

His console log is as follows:[teammate ref obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpWgK.png)

I can't help but notice that these refs appear to be different, yet they are reading from the same place, only on different computers? Is there any reason for this?

Also my code for reference (sorry forgot to add before):

```
async function loadData() {
    try {
        let studentSnapshot = await myFirebase.firestore().collection('students').get()
        if (!studentSnapshot.empty) {
            let studentDoc = studentSnapshot.docs[0].data()
            console.log(studentDoc.teamDocRef)
            let teamDoc = await studentDoc.teamDocRef.get() // this is what throws the error on the other side
        }
    } catch (error) { console.log("Error with loading data", error) }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  I suggest reading this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting the same database? How do you initialize connection?

Comment: yes, they both have the same firebase file with the proper config to the same project

Comment: as it was already mentioned the best would be to create reproducible example as this does not seem to be possible. If you totally sure you can raise a bug here https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs